# Libgdx animation , animates only on Animation.LOOP_RANDOM mode

Tags: android, libgdx, android-animation

I am creating an android game in libgdx engine.My Animation object and rendering code is as

```
rightAnim=new Animation(0.02f, rightRegions);
rightAnim.setPlayMode(Animation.LOOP_RANDOM);
//Rendering
batcher.draw(rightAnim.getKeyFrame(runTime,true),hero.getX(),hero.getY(),hero.getWidth(),hero.getHeight());
```

I can see this animation running only on "LOOP_RANDOM" mode, but I want it to play normal loop.In other loop only 1st frame is drawn for eg. in "LOOP_REVERSED" mode only last frame is drawn.I googled 2 days but couldn't find solution.Please help me out and sorry for my bad English .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
rightAnim.setPlayMode(Animation.LOOP)
```

is the correct play mode for a standard animatin loop, and should give you the behavior you want.  If that is not working, something is probably wrong with the time ranges you are using.

Try increasing the `frameDuration` argument from `0.02` to `0.20` and see if you can at least see your animation play through correctly (if slowly).

Also, make sure your `rightRegions` list is correct.

Finally, what is your code for updating `runTime`?  Make sure that is changing correctly.